# Will I trigger a change event if I use Javascript to set a <option> as selected?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onchange

I've observed that, in Google Chrome, setting an `<option>` as selected via Javascript does not trigger the respective `<select>` tag's change event.

Can I count on this behavior holding true in all other modern browsers?

Comment: You could always try it.  I would say yes, probably.  You generally need to call `element.onchange()` manually if you change the form control value programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an option as selected via JavaScript *or* selecting an option by focusing then using up and down buttons to select, is not accepted as an event by the `onchange()` event handler as evident by the following links :

- http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-156699.html
- http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread205638.html

PS : *A similar situation occurred when i tried to evoke* `<element onmousedown="doStuff();">` *by calling* `element.click();`

Answer (score 1):

Setting any value for any field in JavaScript should not trigger any events.

If they did you would end up in an endless loop of events firing.

If you want, you can "call" the change event manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should hold true. In my experience this works in IE 6 up, Chrome, FF and Safari. I would agree that testing in all browsers you intend supporting is sensible though !

Answer (score 0):

option:selected yes it works I just used it myself. Even held true in IE 6 - IE 8 webkit and FF